# How to detect that I'm running hugo's built in server?

Tags: hugo

Are there any hugo globals that will let me know if hugo is serving its files from the built-in server? I want to display some hints in my partials as to which partial is being rendered so that I can more easily identify where I need to make changes, instead of having to crawl through my codebase.

I think I'd achieve this by placing some if statements in my partials to check for this global, and render a small hint/enable a tooltip letting me know which HTML element belongs in which file. Since the if statements only check for a development environment I think this would be safe to keep in production code.

Let me know if that's a potentially dumb idea though.

Comment: I think this could help: https://gohugo.io/getting-started/configuration/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.Site.IsServer
a boolean to indicate if the site is being served with Hugo’s built-in
server. See hugo server for more information.

So:
{{ if .Site.IsServer }}
LOCAL SITE SERVER!!
{{ end }}

Beyond that, what are you really running into where you need all of what you are describing? I assume their is a deeper issue or earlier issue you are trying to solve that got you into this confusion...

Comment: That's what I was looking for! The issue I'm running into is efficiently finding components in my site. The way I've done it thus far is just have debug tools open, find any class/ids linked to that control, then search for them in my text editor. I figured adding these tooltips could make my development work go by faster in finding components to edit.

Comment: I can't imagine the bizarre situation where what you are describing exists as a situation, but best of luck to you. Possibly what might help, is: https://gohugo.io/variables/files/#readout, as I believe {{.File.Path}} in the shortcode/partial/whatever would then display it's file path meaning you could tell what is generating it.

Comment: Thanks for the link! I am using something like that.